# Limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ of a fraction of successive Hermit polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

I was trying to apply the **ratio test** to

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}
$$

, where $H_n(x)$ is a **Hermite Polynomial**.  Assuming that both $t$ and $x$ are finite, we start with

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{
H_{n+1}(x) t^{n+1} / (n+1)!
}{
H_{n}(x) t^{n} / n!
} \right|
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| 
\frac{H_{n+1}(x)}{H_{n}(x)}
\frac{t}{(n+1)}
 \right|
$$

I know we have the recurrence relations:

$$
H_{n+1}(x) = 2xH_{n}(x) - 2nH_{n-1}(x) 
\\
H_{n}'(x) = 2nH_{n-1}(x)
$$

but I don't see how these help in evaluating the limit.

**Question: Evaluate the following limit:**

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| 
\frac{H_{n+1}(x)}{H_{n}(x)}
\frac{t}{(n+1)}
 \right|
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following representation
$$H_{n}(x)=\frac{n!}{2\pi{i}}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2xz-z^{2}}}{z^{n+1}}$$
You have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{H_{n+1}}{H_{n}(n+1)}|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi{i}}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2xz-z^{2}}}{z^{n+2}}}{(n+1)\frac{n!}{2\pi{i}}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2xz-z^{2}}}{z^{n+1}}}|=$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2xz-z^{2}}}{z^{n+2}}}{\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2xz-z^{2}}}{z^{n+1}}}|=0$$

Comment: Thank you! The limit at the end is zero because $z^{n+2}$ goes to infinity faster than $z^{n+1}$, right? If this is correct, we do not even need to evaluate the integral. And, therefore, do not need to set $|z|=1$?

Comment: Yes! The choice $|z|=1$ is arbitrary, you actually need any contour enclosing the pole at the origin. And why you were wondering about this problem? I mean this is a well-known series, and it converges to $\exp(2xt-t^{2})$...